# How to really remove (and restore) elements from a webpage using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, video, hide, restore

Is it possible to remove (playing) HTML5 / YouTube / Vimeo embedded videos along with sound and then restore them somehow when needed?

I know CSS ways of doing such things, like: `display none; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden`, but the point is when I use them - I can still hear the sound from the videos as they are just hidden.

I'm using Cycle jQuery shortcode and want to remove all the videos from non-active slides, I know there are APIs for each case but I'd love to avoid using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.remove()` selector returns the objects it removes, so you could do this:

```
var deleted = $('#foo').remove();

// Some time later

$('#parent').append(deleted);
```

Comment: looks like remove() doesn't work with Vimeo and HTML5 so I guess it won't affect other videos too. It does absolutely nothing. I'll try to do that with parent-div and update this comment.

Comment: `.remove()` has nothing in conflict with HTML5. What code are you running?

Comment: By HTML5 I meant VideoJS implementation of HTML5 Video that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but have you considered `.detach()`?

http://api.jquery.com/detach/